# Python: Create a class for SQL select and update statement

Tags: python, pymysql

Is there any other way to improve this code? I'm trying to create a class with select and update method then I call it for future use.

**connect.py**

```
import pymysql

class SQL:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cnx = pymysql.connect(host...)
        self.c = self.cnx.cursor()

    def select(self, sql):
        self.c.execute(sql)
        self.sel = self.c.fetchone()
        self.c.close()
        self.cnx.close()
        return self.sel

    def update(self, sql):
        self.c.execute(sql)
        self.upd = self.cnx.commit()
        self.c.close()
        self.cnx.close()
        return self.upd
```

---

```
from connect import SQL

stmt = "SELECT * FROM name;"
result = SQL().select(stmt)
```

Comment: How about to put statements into the class?

Comment: It is Android tutorial but you can refer to https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pymysql

class Connection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.con = pymysql.connect(
            host = 'localhost',
            port = 3306,
            user = 'user',
            password = 'password',
            db = 'dbname',
            autocommit=True,
            charset = 'utf8mb4',
            cursorclass = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
            )
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()

    def _select(self,sql,args=None):
        self.cur.execute(sql,args)
        self.sel = self.cur.fetchone()
        self.cur.close()
        self.con.close()
        return self.sel

    def _selectAll(self,sql,args=None):
        self.cur.execute(sql,args)
        self.sel = self.cur.fetchall()
        self.cur.close()
        self.con.close()
        return self.sel

    def _insert(self,sql,args=None):
        self.ins = self.cur.executemany(sql,args)
        return self.ins

    def _update(self,sql, args=None):
        self.upd = self.cur.executemany(sql,args)
        return self.upd

    def _delete(self, sql, args=None):
        self.delete = self.cur.executemany(sql,args)
        return self.delete
```

I used a logic to repository creating this class, an example(with PyPika) of use is this:

```
  from foo.bar import Connection
  from pypika import Query, Table
    
    users = Table("users")
    
    class UserRepository(Connection):
        def getById(self, args=None):
            query = Query.from_(users).select("*").where(users.tg_id == "%s")
            q = query.get_sql(quote_char=None)
            return self._select(q, args)
```

And now an example of how to invoke the repository:

```
from foo.bar import UserRepository
    def init(user):
       row = UserRepository().getById(user)
       for i in row:
            print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a function in this class  ,function close().use close() in the end of the main().Besides ,use try and except in your every function. Also you can add a reinit function to be called in every function.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a new class logic from my previous answer integrating a pool as well

> db_connect.py

```
import pymysql
from pymysqlpool import ConnectionPool
from config import Session

def create_pool() -> ConnectionPool:
    return ConnectionPool(
        name="pool",
        host=Session.config.HOST,
        port=Session.config.PORT,
        user=Session.config.USER,
        password=Session.config.PASSWORD,
        database=Session.config.DBNAME,
        autocommit=True,
        charset="utf8mb4",
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
    )


class Connection:
    """
    This class handles database connection and inbound queries
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.con = Session.db_pool.get_connection()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args) -> None:
        del args
        self.con.close()

    def _select(self, sql: str, args: tuple = None):
        with self.con.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(sql, args)
            return cursor.fetchone()

    def _select_all(self, sql: str, args: tuple = None):
        with self.con.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(sql, args)
            return cursor.fetchall()

    def _execute_many(self, sql: str, args: list[tuple] = None):
        with self.con.cursor() as cursor:
            return cursor.executemany(sql, args)

    def _execute(self, sql: str, args: tuple = None):
        with self.con.cursor() as cursor:
            return cursor.execute(sql, args)
```

> config.py (with pydantic)

```
from pydantic import BaseSettings

LIST_ENV = (
    ("HOST", "MYSQL_HOST"),
    ("PORT", "MYSQL_PORT"),
    ("USER", "MYSQL_USER"),
    ("PASSWORD", "MYSQL_PASSWORD"),
    ("DBNAME", "MYSQL_DBNAME"),
)


class Config(BaseSettings):
    # Database settings
    HOST: str = "localhost"
    PORT: int = 3306
    USER: str = "root"
    PASSWORD: str
    DBNAME: str

    class Config:
        fields = {name: {"env": env} for name, env in LIST_ENV}
```

> session.py

```
from pymysqlpool import ConnectionPool
from config import Config
from core.utilities.lang import Lang


class Session:
    config: Config
    db_pool: ConnectionPool
```

> Example Repository (user.py)

```
from core.database.db_connect import Connection


class UserRepository(Connection):
    def get_by_id(self, user_id):
        q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE tg_id='%s'"

        return self._select(q, (user_id,))
```

> How to invoke and use repository

```
from core.database.repository import UserRepository
def new_member(id):
  with GroupRepository() as db:
     data = db.get_by_id(id)
```